# Mysql SELECT query group by with sum and avg

Tags: mysql

If I have added "group by date" then sum or avg function is not working.

Here is a table

```
| date         | calories |
|-------------------------|
| 2021-03-28   | 42.50    |
| 2021-03-30   | 500.00   |
| 2021-03-31   | 35.00    |
| 2021-04-01   | 200.00   |
| 2021-04-01   | 35.00    |
```

Here is create Query

```
SELECT CONCAT(round(IF(avg(up.calories), avg(up.calories), 0), 2), "kcal") as avg, CONCAT(round(IF(SUM(up.calories), SUM(up.calories), 0), 2), "kcal") as total_burned
FROM `tbl` as `up`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN "2021-03-28" AND "2021-04-03"
AND `calories` != '0'
GROUP BY `date`
```

Below is my query result

```
| avg          | total_burned |
|-----------------------------|
| 42.50        | 42.50        |
| 500.00       | 500.00       |
| 35.00        | 35.00        |
| 235.00       | 235.00       |
```

But actually, I want to this type of result

```
| avg          | total_burned |
|-----------------------------|
| 203.13       | 812.50       |
```

Comment: 'If I have added "group by date" then sum or avg function is not working.' - then why did you add it , what did you have a problem with that you thought grouping would be a solution?

Comment: @P.Salmon, If I have not added "group by date" then avg is not proper

Comment: Hi @Pankaj 

As per your requirement group by is not required.

The GROUP BY statement groups rows that have the same values into summary rows, like "find the number of customers in each country".

The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT(), MAX(), MIN(), SUM(), AVG()) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Answer (score 1):

Roll your own

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
create table t( date date, calories decimal(10,2));
insert into t values
( '2021-03-28'   , 42.50    ),
( '2021-03-30'   , 500.00   ),
( '2021-03-31'   , 35.00    ),
( '2021-04-01'   , 200.00   ),
( '2021-04-01'   , 35.00    );

select sum(calories) sumcal,sum(calories) / count(distinct date) calcavg, avg(calories)
from t;

+--------+------------+---------------+
| sumcal | calcavg    | avg(calories) |
+--------+------------+---------------+
| 812.50 | 203.125000 |    162.500000 |
+--------+------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)
```